# Why does `waitUntilInstanceTerminated` throw an error with raw JSON data about the EC2 instance?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm creating a contrived code example for showcasing how to use the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) to create and destroy an EC2 instance.

I'm able to successfully create the instance and call the `TerminateInstancesCommand`. However, when I use the `waitUntilInstanceTerminated` function it immediately throws the following error:

```
Error: {"result":{"state":"FAILURE","reason":{/* output from DescribeInstancesCommand */}}
    at checkExceptions (/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ec2/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-waiter/dist-cjs/waiter.js:34:15)
    at waitUntilInstanceTerminated (/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ec2/dist-cjs/waiters/waitForInstanceTerminated.js:84:46)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an EC2 instance, it takes some time to start up. Check the instance state either with the AWS Management Console or with the SDK using the `DescribeInstancesCommand`. You'll see this error if your state is still `pending` when you try to `waitUntilInstanceTerminated`.

Try implementing [waitUntilInstanceRunning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ec2/globals.html#waituntilinstancerunning) before you try and terminate it.